# Error: 'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices' when trying to submit a ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I am getting the error 'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices' when trying to submit a ModelForm. The values being passed though from the front end look to be correct (the PK for each) and all required values are being provided yet it still doesn't return me any cleaned data

I am still quite new to Django and googling hasn't got me results that work

(Also I am using crispy forms for styling the front end)

**forms.py**

```
    code = forms.CharField(required=True)
    itemtype = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=True, queryset=ItemType.objects.all())
    location = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=True, queryset=Location.objects.all())
    parent = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=Item.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['code', 'itemtype', 'location', 'parent']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

            super(CreateItemWithParentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            for field in self.fields:
                self.fields[field].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}

            self.fields['itemtype'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: "{0}".format(obj.name)
            self.fields['location'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: "{0}".format(obj.address)
            self.fields['parent'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: "{0}".format(obj.code)

            self.helper = FormHelper(self)
            self.helper.form_show_labels = True
            self.helper.form_id = 'createitemform'

            self.helper.layout = Layout(
                Fieldset("Create New Item",
                         Field('code', css_class="mt-2", placeholder="Code", name="code", id="code"),
                         Field('itemtype', css_class="mt-2", name="itemtype", placeholder="Item type", css_id="itemtype"),
                         Field('location', css_class="mt-2", name="location", placeholder="Location", css_id="location"),
                         Field('parent', css_class="mt-2", name="parent", placeholder="Parent Item", css_id="parent"),
                         Button('createitemformbutton', 'Submit', css_class="btn-light"),
                         css_class='border',
                    )
            )
```

**views.py**

```
class CreateItemWithParent(FormView):
    """
    create a new item with specified parent
    """
    template_name = 'add_item.html'
    form_class = CreateItemWithParentForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('add_item_success')

    def get_initial(self):
            return {"pk": self.kwargs.get('pk')}

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ...
        return context

    def clean_itemtype(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['itemtype']
        return data

    def clean_location(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['location']
        return data

    def clean_parent(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['parent']
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):

        return super().form_valid(form)


def save_new_item_with_parent(request):

    options = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        item_form = CreateItemWithParentForm(request.POST)

        if item_form.is_valid():

            child = _add_item(item_form.cleaned_data['code'], int(item_form.cleaned_data['itemtype']), int(item_form.cleaned_data['location']))

            parent = item_form.cleaned_data['parent']['id']

            if child != -1:
                if parent != "-1":
                    if _add_itemitem(int(parent), int(child)):
                        options['success'] = True
                    else:
                        options['success'] = False
                else:
                    options['success'] = True
            else:
                options['success'] = False            
        else:
            print('form not valid')
            print(item_form.errors)

    return JsonResponse(options)

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['code', 'itemtype', 'location', 'parent']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

            super(CreateItemWithParentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            for field in self.fields:
                self.fields[field].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}

            self.fields['itemtype'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: "{0}".format(obj.name)
            self.fields['location'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: "{0}".format(obj.address)
            self.fields['parent'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: "{0}".format(obj.code)

            self.helper = FormHelper(self)
            self.helper.form_show_labels = True
            self.helper.form_id = 'createitemform'

            self.helper.layout = Layout(
                Fieldset("Create New Item",
                         Field('code', css_class="mt-2", placeholder="Code", name="code", id="code"),
                         Field('itemtype', css_class="mt-2", name="itemtype", placeholder="Item type", css_id="itemtype"),
                         Field('location', css_class="mt-2", name="location", placeholder="Location", css_id="location"),
                         Field('parent', css_class="mt-2", name="parent", placeholder="Parent Item", css_id="parent"),
                         Button('createitemformbutton', 'Submit', css_class="btn-light"),
                         css_class='border',
                         )
            )
```

**models.py**

```
class ItemType(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(default='')
    start = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(default='')
    address = models.TextField(default='')
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

class Item(models.Model):
    ITEMTYPE_CHOICES = ItemType.objects.values('id', 'name')
    LOCATION_CHOICES = Location.objects.values('id', 'address')
    # children = models.ManyToManyField('Item', through='ItemItem')
    code = models.TextField(default='')
    itemtype = models.ForeignKey('ItemType', on_delete=DO_NOTHING, choices=ITEMTYPE_CHOICES)
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location', on_delete=DO_NOTHING, choices=ITEMTYPE_CHOICES)
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=True, auto_now=True)
    edited = models.DateTimeField(null=True, auto_now=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

**HTML template (with Jquery)**

```
<section class="container-fluid" id="home">
    <section class="container-fluid" id="intro_text">
        <h2>Add Item</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="mainpane" class="col-md-12">
                <div class="dd" id="success"></div>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% crispy form %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button-id-createitemformbutton").on("click", function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : "{% url "save_new_item_with_parent" %}",
            type : "POST",
            data: $("#createitemform").serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                if(result.success){
                    $("#success").html('Your item has been recorded in the database. <a href="/item/list/">View all items?</a>');
                    $("#success").removeClass('dd');

                    // reset form
                    $("#code").val('');
                    $("#id_itemtype").val(1);
                    $("#id_location").val(1);
                    if(window.location.pathname.length < 11){
                        $("#id_parent").val(-1);
                    }

                }
                if(!result.success){
                    alert(result.errors);
                }
            },
        });
    });

});
</script>
```